# Modal displaying same information for all links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have just created my first modal using the bootstrap code, i have all the information i want to display sorted out but the 'read more' link always points to the first modal. I understand i am going to have to set each modal to have its own unique id i guess but im just unsure how to go about this. I'm Not to familiar with javascript which i guess i might have to get into to get this working properly.

Be really grateful for any advice

Many Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/rufusbear/f6xkk4ch/

```
    <div class="one-fourth">
        <div class="image-bg">
          <img src="img/Tracey.jpg" alt="Tracey Riddington" />
          <h5>Tracey Riddington<br>Manager</h5>
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tracey Riddington - Manager</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <img class="modal-img" src="img/Tracey.jpg" alt="Tracey Riddington" />
                  <p>Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).<br><br>Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member). Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).<br><br>Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.<br><br>Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="one-fourth">
        <div class="image-bg">
          <img src="img/KevinLock.jpeg" alt="Kevin Lock" />
          <h5>Kevin Lock<br>Grounds Manager</h5>
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Kevin Lock - Grounds Manager</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <img class="modal-img" src="img/KevinLock.jpeg" alt="Kevin Lock" />
                  <p>...</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    /*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */


/*!
 * Generated using the Bootstrap Customizer (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=99797a3288748184e66844825ee3172f)
 * Config saved to config.json and https://gist.github.com/99797a3288748184e66844825ee3172f
 */


/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */


/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */


   .one-fourth {
  width: 23%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0% 1% 2.5%;
}

.image-bg {
  background: #e9e8e6;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 95%;
}

hr {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0
}

button {
  overflow: visible
}

hr {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0
}

.sr-only-focusable:active,
.sr-only-focusable:focus {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  clip: auto
}

[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #718373;
}

.btn-primary .badge {
  color: #718373;
  background-color: #fff
}

.btn-lg {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 3px
}

.btn-sm {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px
}

.btn-xs {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px
}

.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}

.btn-block+.btn-block {
  margin-top: 5px
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity .15s linear;
  transition: opacity .15s linear
}

.fade.in {
  opacity: 1
}

.collapse {
  display: none
}

.collapse.in {
  display: block
}

.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  -o-transition-property: height, visibility;
  transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .35s;
  -o-transition-duration: .35s;
  transition-duration: .35s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: ease
}

.close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20)
}

button.close {
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0)
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #718373;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0)
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
  opacity: .5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50)
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5
}

.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: -2px
}

.modal-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5
}

.modal-footer .btn+.btn {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.modal-footer .btn-group .btn+.btn {
  margin-left: -1px
}

.modal-footer .btn-block+.btn-block {
  margin-left: 0
}

.modal-scrollbar-measure {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto
  }
  .modal-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  }
  .modal-sm {
    width: 300px
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 900px
  }
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.modal-header:before,
.modal-header:after,
.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table
}

.clearfix:after,
.modal-header:after,
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both
}

.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

.pull-right {
  float: right !important
}

.pull-left {
  float: left !important
}

.hide {
  display: none !important
}

.show {
  display: block !important
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden
}

.text-hide {
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important
}

.affix {
  position: fixed
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer it is working..<br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Read More</button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the id of second one to myModal2
and the value of data-target in second read more add myModal2

https://jsfiddle.net/f6xkk4ch/2/

```
<div class="one-fourth">
    <div class="image-bg">
      <img src="img/Tracey.jpg" alt="Tracey Riddington" />
      <h5>Tracey Riddington<br>Manager</h5>
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tracey Riddington - Manager</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <img class="modal-img" src="img/Tracey.jpg" alt="Tracey Riddington" />
              <p>Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).<br><br>Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member). Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).<br><br>Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.<br><br>Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="one-fourth">
    <div class="image-bg">
      <img src="img/KevinLock.jpeg" alt="Kevin Lock" />
      <h5>Kevin Lock<br>Grounds Manager</h5>
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Read More</button>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Kevin Lock - Grounds Manager</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <img class="modal-img" src="img/KevinLock.jpeg" alt="Kevin Lock" />
              <p>...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much, didnt think it would be as easy as that! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

### I have modified your code.. please check this

```
<div class="one-fourth">
        <div class="image-bg">
          <img src="img/Tracey.jpg" alt="Tracey Riddington" />
          <h5>Tracey Riddington<br>Manager</h5>
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="first" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tracey Riddington - Manager</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <img class="modal-img" src="img/Tracey.jpg" alt="Tracey Riddington" />
                  <p>Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).<br><br>Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member). Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).<br><br>Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).Manager of Fennes Shooting School for 25 years. Has been shooting for 33 years, coaching for 28 years and has shot for England 12 times.<br><br>Qualified CPSA Coach (Life Member) APSI (Fellow Member).</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="one-fourth">
        <div class="image-bg">
          <img src="img/KevinLock.jpeg" alt="Kevin Lock" />
          <h5>Kevin Lock<br>Grounds Manager</h5>
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Read More</button>
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Kevin Lock - Grounds Manager</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <img class="modal-img" src="img/KevinLock.jpeg" alt="Kevin Lock" />
                  <p>...</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much, didnt think it would be as easy as that! Thanks so much

Comment: Explain whats the issue and what you modified would make this a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id (i.e `id="myModal"`) for both the modals. Note that `id` should be a unique value.

1. Change the `data-target="#myModal"` attribute in **second** button to `data-target="#myModal2"`
2. Also change the `id="myModal"` of **second** modal to `id="myModal2"`.

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f6xkk4ch/1/)

Comment: Perfect thank you so much, didnt think it would be as easy as that! Thanks so much